# Zend Framework; check if a controller exists or not

Tags: php, zend-framework

I searched on Google, and I got this code to check if a controller exists or not.

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
if ($front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request)) {
    // Controller exists
}
```

But I don't know where I should put this code. What is `$request`?
I'm in *Boostrap.php*. I have `_initRoute`, I need to check if a controller doesn't exist, if it doesn't then I will add a new route.

---

Updated after first answer. I have some routes in Boostrap.php

```
public function _initRoute() {


    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute(
        'username',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':username',
            array('controller'=>'profile',
                  'action'=>'index')
        )
    );

    $router->addRoute(
        'username/sets',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':username/sets',
            array('controller'=>'profile',
                  'action'=>'sets')
        )
    );


}
```

This Routes, will make mydomain.com/{username} show content same as mydomain.com/profile/index/username/{username}

But the problem is, when I type mydomain.com/{anything or any controller} , it routes as I define on Boostrap. So, I think, I need to check the controller is existing or not, if it doesn't then do the routes.

Am I wrong? After first answer, I added the plugin, and put it under _initPlugin to register it. But look like it not work.

### This is my boostrap file:

```
<?php


//Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('paginator.phtml');

class Plugin_MyX extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $dispatcher = $front->getDispatcher();

        if (!$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {

            $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $router = $front->getRouter();
            $router->addRoute(
                'username',
                new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':username',
                    array('controller'=>'profile',
                          'action'=>'index')
                )
            );

            $router->addRoute(
                'username/sets',
                new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':username/sets',
                    array('controller'=>'profile',
                          'action'=>'sets')
                )
            );


        } else {
            // exist
        }



    }


}




class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{


    protected function _initPlugin() {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Plugin_MyX());
    }

    public function _initRoute() {


    }


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom 404 page?

Comment: No, I'm trying to add some routes, but only add for none-existing controllers only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put that code in a [Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) since the request object does not yet exist at bootstrap time.

The `$request` variable in question is an object of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`.  This object is initially created when the front controller goes to dispatch a request.

You could register a `routeStartup` plugin and place the code there.  That would be the earliest point at which you can use the Request object.  All controller plugin chains will pass the request object to your plugin except for `dispatchLoopShutdown()`.

Here is sample plugin code:

```
class Application_Plugin_Example
{
    public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        if ($front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request)) {
            // Controller exists
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to just handle 404 errors, this is what the [ErrorHandler plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler) can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're dealing with now.  It seems to me like checking if it is dispatchable and then setting your routes if not could work.  But I see your problem, if you create those very basic routes, they will in effect overrule default routes which you definitely don't want.  Did you have success with your method?

Comment: I got my answer after 2 days thinking. Thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your routes from most specific to less specific. Also think about whether you can't have any other option in your URL - like /u/*:username* or /user/:username, which would solve the problem ;)

Also defining routes for each end every controller would solve it - create:

```
/controller-name/
/profile-controller-name/
... with
/:username
at the end of the list
```

That way any controller would be matched earlier and would work. And only controllers not listed would "fall through" to the :username route.